# How to get all cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Let's say I have a UITableView which has multiple rows. I want to get all the UITableViewCells as an NSArray at a certain point of time. I have tried

```
[tableView visibleCells]
```

but there is a problem with this approach: I can not have all those cells which are not currently in the current screen. So I turned to another approach:

```
-(NSArray *)cellsForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
    for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
        NSInteger rows =  [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   // **here, for those cells not in current screen, cell is nil**
            [cells addObject:cell];
        }
    }
    return cells;
}
```

but seems that this approach still can not get those cells which are not displayed in the screen. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What's the point on getting all the `UITableViewCells`? It would be much easier (and less expensive) to work with your data source...

Comment: i have some text input fields in each cell, and each cell has references to those text input fields. I need to get all those values. So i was planing to first get all those cells, and then loop in those cells and get the text field reference to retrive text values.

Comment: The text from your `UITextFields` didn't magically pop there.. So you should rely on your data source, and not in UI elements.

Comment: The problem with the above is that when you have static cells, the TableView is the data source ( or storyboard is the data source to be precise ). iOS should add a method to enumerate static cells ( from storyboard's object ). Otherwise, one has to parse xml from the storyboard, which seems like a hack. Have better ideas?

Comment: Don't do it this way (with possible exception that you have a small table, and have defined the cells as not being reusable). The recommended way to use tableviews is to maintain state in a separate *model*. *As user makes changes, you update that model with the changes*. You don't do so by iterating over cells, rather you add handlers on each field's `editingDidEnd` or similar method.

Comment: @RuiPeres "didn't magically pop there." We're talking about UITextFields. This is a field where the *user* inputs data. So, the data is *not yet in the data source*. As with OP, I have a data entry screen that's using a TableViewController (like Calendar app's "New Event" screen). In order to unwind Segue, I need to collect the data from the TableView's cells.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think thats possible, simply because the tableView doesn't store all cells. It uses a caching mechanism which only stores some cells, that are not visible, for reuse.

Why do you need all cells? Maybe you can achieve, what you're trying to do, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Say i have a text input field on each cell, and each cell also has a reference to this text input field. What i want to do is to get all the values in those text input fields.

Comment: Is the content in the tableView i.e. the number of cells etc. dependent on some dynamic data or are you trying to archieve sth. like the contacts app on iPhone? If you always have the same cells in the tableView, you could set it up as static (there is an option for that in IB) and then connect the TextFields to IBOutlets.

Comment: If it's dynamic I guess you'd have to manually set a TargetAction on each of the textfields - f.e. for EditingDidEnd - and in the handler save the value somewhere.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the simplest solution in Swift 3.0

```
func getAllCells() -> [UITableViewCell] {

    var cells = [UITableViewCell]()
    // assuming tableView is your self.tableView defined somewhere
    for i in 0...tableView.numberOfSections-1
    {
        for j in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)-1
        {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) {

               cells.append(cell)
            }

        }
    }
 return cells
 }
```

Comment: As mentioned before this approach only useful for visible cells

Answer (score 8):

Each time you create a cell you can add it to a NSMutableArray which you can parse whenever you need:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *Cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Custom_Cell_Id"];
    if (Cell == NULL)
    {
        Cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Custom_Cell_Id"]];
        [Cells_Array addObject:Cell];
    }
}

- (void) DoSomething
{
    for (int i = 0;i < [Cells count];i++)
    {
        CustomCell *Cell = [Cells objectAtIndex:i];
        //Access cell components
    }
}
```

Comment: i had like 5 cells that were custom class objects and didn't feel like adding a listener to update settings so i added the cells to an nsmutablearray as you suggested. But i eliminated this line CustomCell *Cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Custom_Cell_Id"]; and instead checked if it was in the array for re-use and it seems to work.

Comment: This is useless, in fact it's a massive memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

#### Functional solution swift 5.0

```
extension UITableView {
    /**
     * Returns all cells in a table
     * ## Examples:
     * tableView.cells // array of cells in a tableview
     */
    public var cells: [UITableViewCell] {
      (0..<self.numberOfSections).indices.map { (sectionIndex: Int) -> [UITableViewCell] in
          (0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex)).indices.compactMap { (rowIndex: Int) -> UITableViewCell? in
              self.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex))
          }
      }.flatMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: @enonist: not working error: Value of type 'UITableView?' has no member 'cells'

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be misunderstanding how the `UITableView` is implemented. The important point to understand is that cells that are not visible don't actually exist (or at least they might not)

As the `UITableView` is scrolled the old cells are replaced by new cells by virtue of       `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` 
 used in

```
-(UITableViewCell) cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: thats completely wrong, there are 3 extra ones at all times

Answer (score 1):

**However, a simpler implementation to get the current cells would be using Set i.e O(1)**

```
/// Reference to all cells.
private var allCells = Set<UITableViewCell>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Your_Cell_ID") as! UITableViewCell
    if !allCells.contains(cell) { allCells.insert(cell) }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: ok, adding is O(1), but how about evaluating cells that are already cleared? I bet we need to check for nullability then - or have a memory leak

Comment: @Antek good call, also when a cell get deleted we need to remove that cell from `allCells`

Comment: This retains the cells when the table might want to deinit the non-visible ones. It happens when there is a memory warning. Instead its best to keep a weak reference.

Comment: This is useless, in fact it';s a massive memory leak

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found a trick for this issue. Try this ;)

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.contentSize.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
```

UITableView call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` according height of `tableView.frame` so you should update the height of your tableView.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**
UITableView does reuse cells, that means you can load 100 items into UITableView , however you only display lets say 10 items at the time. If the user wants to display another items he needs to scroll. Therefore for memory optimisation `UITableView`  loads only 13 cells (10 cells displayed + 3 cells preloaded). If you want to get all visible cells (10 cells in our example), you can use:

```
let visibleCells = yourTableView.visiblecells
```

However if you want to get all loaded cells (13 cells in our example) I recommend using following extension:

```
extension UITableView {

func getAllCells() -> [UITableViewCell] {
    var cells = [UITableViewCell]()
    for i in 0..<self.numberOfSections
    {
        for j in 0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
        {
            if let cell = self.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: j, section: i)) {
                cells.append(cell)
            }
            
        }
    }
    return cells
}
```

}

You can then get your all cells by calling:

```
let allLoadedCells = yourtableView.getAllCells()
```

Comment: it does seem a bit inefficient with very large tables ...

Comment: @Fattie yes it is inefficient, but the answer to the question. Best practice is to avoid getting all the cells..

Comment: true enough, MSO.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want value of those text fields? If Yes, you can access via tag property of the textfield with indexpath.row

Comment: yes, that is just what i want. but how can i get the textfield first. i used interface builder to add textfield to the view, not code. thanks anyway.